# Single page: set elements at bottom of page in any browser or device

Tags: html, css

I am developing a website where I have a top menu and a background image with some text on the home page. This covers the whole screen. BUT at the bottom of the screen there have to be 3 blocks who show up at the bottom of any screen or device. I am able to to this for Chrome but for Firefox for example the blocks are way far down at IE the same... What I want:

[image]

I am currently doing applying following code on the div containing the 3 blocks:

```
position: relative;
top: -150px;
```

But as mentioned above in another browser this div shows up to low so the user won't see it until he scrolls...

Any solutions here?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You want those three blocks to be at the bottom of the page regardless of whether the user has scrolled to the top of the page, bottom of the page or somewhere in the middle? If so, do a search for "sticky footer."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple change:

```
position: fixed;
bottom: 0;
```

Better idea to wrap it inside another `<div class="bottom-stuff">` and give the rules to `.bottom-stuff`.

Comment: No it doesn't have to stay there. It has to be at the bottom but when the user scrolls the entire blocks have to become visible and all the content under it such as footer etc

Comment: If not, just give `position: absolute;`. As simple as that.

Comment: embarrassingly easy but thanks anyway!